# Using Shiny to enable variables to be changed in a linear regression model

Tags: r, model, shiny, regression, forecasting

My aim is for a user to be able to change the inputs to a linear regression model in a Shiny application, and for the Shiny application to show the forecast based on the value of the variables given.

ie. a Chicken shop uses the variable Temperature and Day of the week to predict sales. I want a user to be able to change these variables to see the different forecasts.

```
calculateModel <- function(data,input){
  regCT <- reactive({tslm(Total ~ Monday,data=data)})
  nextCT <- data.frame(Monday=input$Monday)
  fCT <- forecast(regCT,newdata=nextCT)
  return(fCT)
}

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Chicken"),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("main_plot", height = "300px")),
      box(sliderInput("Monday","Monday",0,1,1)
      )
    )
  )
)
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

dataInput <- reactive({

calculateModel(daily,input)
})

  output$main_plot <- renderPlot({
    input$Monday
    plot(fCT)

  })

})
shinyApp(ui,server)
```

This is a very rough outline of what I assume the code would look like.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe this app can hellp https://rich.shinyapps.io/regression/

Comment: @Keniajin it doesnt help with how the new data frame that is fed into the linear regression model also has to change, and how to display that forecast in a plot.